# Layout 80% of display:table

Tags: html, css

Am trying to make a modal popup [centered, position:fixed], whose central section (#scroller) has a min height of 600px and a max-height of 80% of the height of the screen.

After trying all the usual tricks, I'm still not getting anywhere.

It works fine on the min-height, but not on the max height.

There is no doubt another SO question on this, but I have read dozens, and not gotten anywhere.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Ders/1/

```
<div class='modal'>
    <form action='../dataHandler.php'>
        <figure>
            <h5>Header</h5>
            <div id='scroller'></div>
            <p class='after'>PostContent</p>
        </figure>
    </form>
</div>


<style>
html{height:100%;}
body{min-height:100%}

.modal{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    table-layout: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 7;
    background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.5);
    text-align:center;
    }
form {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
figure{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 10px solid #888888;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #2AB7EC inset, 0 2px 0 0 #156785, 0 5px 3px #999999;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 150px;
    min-width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
    }
#scroller{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    max-height:80%;
    overflow:auto;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an much easier way to setup Modals: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hT5dx/1/

HTML:

```
<div class='modal_shadow'>
    <div class='modal' >
        <div class='modal_content' >
            <h2>title</h2>
            <p>
               Bacon ipsum dolor ...
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal_shadow {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background: rgba(80,80,80,0.5);
}

.modal {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;   
    max-height: 80%;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    overflow:auto;

    /* vertical center */
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 50px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 50px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 50px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 50px);
    transform: translate(0px, 50px);
}
```

You could adapt this to you code.

Comment: I tried it using only one line of text, and it is not centered. I need it to be centered, with the modal popup never shrinking to less than x pixels, and never growing to more than a certain percentage of the screen, with the overflow being in the element containing the text.

Comment: Incidentally, what do you gain by using the browser specific translate instead of the standard position:relative;?

Comment: In this case the position Property doesn't matter, because there isn't any Position set.

Comment: The one Line of Text is not centered, because it's not told to do so. Just the Container around the Text ist centered. If you want to do so, you could add `.modal_content { text-align: center; }` to the css.

Comment: "Am trying to make a modal popup [centered..", I need the popup to be vertically and horizontally centered. The text inside of it does not need to be centered. In your code, if the popup has only one line of text, the popup would not be vertically centered - it would be 50px from the top of the page.

Comment: I found out I've forgot some parts (container height, and the position from top).  The '50px' values must be %. Here is a fixed Version: http://jsfiddle.net/hT5dx/2/